# aggregate sets into bigger sets in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

In my dataset, I have a column `A` that is a list of integers, that represent a set of integers.
I want to aggregate all these sets into the set that represents the union (still represented as a list I guess).
Is there a "simple" way to do this?
What I've done is:

```
agg(array_distinct(flatten(collect_list("A")))
```

but this seems inefficient as it seems that at some point, there will be the totally flatened list in memory that contains all duplicates

Comment: The other option would be to explode the column `A`, then agg and `collect_set`

Comment: @blackbishop yes this was the initial idea I had, but I think it's even worse in terms of data processing than what I suggested, as it requires a shuffle